# What are some nice projects to do on Knowledge graphs?

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, knowledge-base

Okay, so coming straight to the point, I have to do a major project to demonstrate the use cases and advantages of using knowledge graphs. I have seen some ideas in internet like fraud detection and movie recommendations system but quite not convinced with them. Please suggest any good idea.
Thanks.